# In a PL/SQL procedure, how do I pass a table name as a parameter?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A(tab IN <table - what should I write here?>) AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tab VALUES(123);
END A;
```

How can I specify that the parameter `tab` is a table name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.  Instead you need to pass it in as a VARCHAR2 string and then use Dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A(tab IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || tab || 'VALUES(123)';
END A;
```

Read up about [Dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm) and be aware of the issues it can bring if used unwisely, such as poorer performance, scalability and security.

Comment: thanks! Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440516).