# How do I use dynamic SQL to declare a column name derived from a table name?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

Building on [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439278/in-a-pl-sql-procedure-how-do-i-pass-a-table-name-as-a-parameter/3439288#3439288) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439278):

If I want to do something like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A(tab IN VARCHAR2) IS
tab.col_name <column> --static declaration (column name always remains the same)
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || tab(col_name) || 'VALUES(123)';
END A;
```

**How can I use Dynamic SQL in the above case?**

Comment: That is an excellent question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example passes in a table name and a column name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
  ( tab IN VARCHAR2
  , col_name IN VARCHAR2
  ) IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || tab || '(' || col_name || ') VALUES(123)';
END A;
```

You need to realise that everything after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE must be a string that contains some valid SQL.  A good way to verify this is to set it up in a variable and print it to the screen:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
  ( tab IN VARCHAR2
  , col_name IN VARCHAR2
  ) IS
   v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'INSERT INTO ' || tab || '(' || col_name || ') VALUES(123)';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL='||v_sql);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END A;
```

This should then display something like the following in SQL Plus:

> SQL=INSERT INTO mytable(mycolumn)
>   VALUES(123)

(provided server output is turned on).

**EDIT**: Since you want the column name to be a local variable that always has the same value, this could be done as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A (tab IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   col_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'MYCOLUMN';
   v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'INSERT INTO ' || tab || '(' || col_name || ') VALUES(123)';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL='||v_sql);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END A;
```

Comment: What if I do not want to pass a column name as parameter but instead want to **declare** it in the procedure. Is that possible?

Comment: Will the column name always be the same?  If not, is your procedure supposed to somehow find out?  Please explain further what you need.